# TP-Link VIGI C540 - Request static snapshot with ONVIF

Tags: ip, rtsp, snapshot, ip-camera, onvif

I've recently purchased a PTZ camera from TP-Link (**VIGI C540**) and I'd like to use it to periodically capture static snapshots and process them using my script. The script runs in a lightweight environment, so it's necessary for the camera to return a simple JPEG image instead of a full RTSP stream.

I was unable to find any path or method that would directly return an image, something like **/snapshot.jpg**. Since this is an ONVIF compliant camera, I've decided to play around with it and see if I can get the snapshot that way.

First I've executed the `GetCapabilities` command to see properties about the camera. To my surprise, it appears that this model only supports ONVIF specification `2.1`, which according to the [specification history](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/specification-history/) came out in June 2011. Note that this is even after updating the firmware to the latest version (*2.0.3 Build 230215 Rel.77661n*).

```xml
<tt:SupportedVersions>
    <tt:Major>2</tt:Major>
    <tt:Minor>1</tt:Minor>
</tt:SupportedVersions>
```

I find this quite strange, but luckily for me, this version supports the `GetSnapshotUri` command, which I'm looking for. The documentation is available at https://www.onvif.org/specs/DocMap-2.1.html?441d4a&441d4a - 5.16.1 Request snapshot URI.

I proceeded to attempt to run this function. The default profile name for me is `profile_1`, so I set that as the `ProfileToken` element. See the full body below:

```xml
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetSnapshotUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
        <ProfileToken>profile_1</ProfileToken>
    </GetSnapshotUri>
</s:Body>
```

Here is the response body:

`500 Internal Server Error`

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <SOAP-ENV:Code>
            <SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Receiver</SOAP-ENV:Value>
            <SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
                <SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:ActionNotSupported</SOAP-ENV:Value>
            </SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
        </SOAP-ENV:Code>
        <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
            <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">NVT does not support the function</SOAP-ENV:Text>
        </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Does this indicate that the recent camera model doesn't support an ordinary function like requesting a static image in JPEG? I was successfully able to set up RTSP (unusable in my environment) and even use ONVIF to perform other actions like pan and tilt, but this is absolutely ruining the experience for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm still searching for an answer. Will probably have to resort to buying a different model.

Answer (score 0):

add it to  onvier ip camera monitor app  , you can see if it has screenshot url